# Renaming a save file reverts the save to an older one in MyBoy! emulator?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-third-generation, my-boy

I have FireRed and LeafGreen on MyBoy! and am trying to manage my .sav files. I changed the filename of both the .zip file and the .sav file to clean them up (they had long and unwieldy names from when I downloaded them) and when I reopened the game... the save file was a save from MONTHS ago. All the data was intact and it worked just fine, but it wasn't current.

This happened for both games. This happens regardless of what folder they're in (so long as they're in the same one) and regardless of what I rename it to. If I upload the files to Windows, rename them, then put them back on the device - SAME FILES, JUST DIFFERENT NAMES - I open a completely different save file in the game.

Has this happened to anyone else? Suggestions? Thankfully I backed up my data, but I'm so confused.

Comment: Do the save files represent emulation-level save states, or in-game saves? Try saving both ways, then renaming, and see what happens after that

Comment: Both. The .sav files I'm renaming are the in-game saves. But when I rename the .zip file, the emulator state saves change with it. The states I can load ALSO represent the save file from months ago. It's as if both save types are somehow tied to the filename.

Comment: ***UPDATE*** It appears the save file isn't being pulled from the same folder, but from the MyBoy/save folder. It takes precedence over the file in the same folder as the game.  Now I'm REALLY confused.

Comment: What happens if you remove the saves from the MyBoy folder? does it revert to using the saves in the game folder?